# Malformed IP address error

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, geoip, geolite2

I am trying to run a project but everytime I try loading a specific page it throws away the following stack of error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restplus/api.py", line 536, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/nitin/Desktop/open-event-orga-server/app/views/users/events.py", line 91, in create_view
    current_timezone = get_current_timezone()
  File "/home/nitin/Desktop/open-event-orga-server/app/helpers/wizard/helpers.py", line 17, in get_current_timezone
    match = geolite2.lookup(get_real_ip(True) or '127.0.0.1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geoip.py", line 364, in lookup
    return self._get_actual_db().lookup(ip_addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geoip.py", line 204, in lookup
    return self._lookup(ip_addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geoip.py", line 249, in _lookup
    packed_addr = pack_ip(ip_addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geoip.py", line 37, in pack_ip
    raise ValueError('Malformed IP address')
ValueError: Malformed IP address
[2017-01-22 00:34:24 +0000] [6835] [ERROR] Error handling request /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=8bed14818d4046edb35bbc87f27d5164
```

And I am unable to figure out what exactly is a malformed IP address and the reason behind this error.

Following is the get_current_timezone() function:

```
def get_current_timezone():
    match = geolite2.lookup(get_real_ip(True) or '127.0.0.1')
    if match is not None:
        return match.timezone
    else:
        return 'UTC'
```

And following is the get_real_ip() method:

```
def get_real_ip(local_correct=False):
    try:
        if 'X-Forwarded-For' in request.headers:
            ip = request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For")[0].rpartition(' ')[-1]
        else:
            ip = request.remote_addr or None

        if local_correct and (ip == '127.0.0.1' or ip == '0.0.0.0'):
            ip = urlopen('http://ip.42.pl/raw').read()  # On local test environments
    except:
        ip = None

    return ip
```

And the following is the portion of create event view that is creating this problem.:

```
@events.route('/create/', defaults={'step': ''})
@events.route('/create/<step>')
def create_view(step):
    if step != '':
        return redirect(url_for('.create_view', step=''))

    hash = get_random_hash()
    if CallForPaper.query.filter_by(hash=hash).all():
        hash = get_random_hash()

    current_timezone = get_current_timezone()

    return render_template(
        'gentelella/admin/event/wizard/wizard.html',
        current_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
        event_types=DataGetter.get_event_types(),
        event_licences=DataGetter.get_event_licences(),
        event_topics=DataGetter.get_event_topics(),
        event_sub_topics=DataGetter.get_event_subtopics(),
        timezones=DataGetter.get_all_timezones(),
        cfs_hash=hash,
        current_timezone=current_timezone,
        payment_countries=DataGetter.get_payment_countries(),
        payment_currencies=DataGetter.get_payment_currencies(),
        included_settings=get_module_settings())
```

Comment: Could you provide the src of get_real_ip?

Comment: `"malformed IP address"` means that you try to use text ie. `"Hello World!"` instead of IP address ie. `"192.168.0.1"`. So check first `print( get_real_ip(True) )`

Comment: Using an IP(eg. 127.0.0.1 instead of typing localhost) always lands me on 404 page. @furas

Comment: check what you get in `print( get_real_ip(True) )` - maybe it gives some strange result (error message) which later is used as IP in `geolite2.lookup()` and you get error message.

Comment: No luck doing that :(